# AES Encryption : Encrypt using Arduino and decrypt using Java

Tags: java, encryption, arduino, cryptography, aes

I want to encrypt a text using Arduino and decrypt it using Java. I tried this code from [this link](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/15156/simple-aes-encryption-example) but without success.

I am using this [Arduino library](https://github.com/DavyLandman/AESLib) for encryption on the Arduino and the Java Cryptographic Extension (JCE) framework for the Java side.

This the Arduino code:

```
#include <AESLib.h>  //replace the ( with < to compile (forum posting issue)
#include <Base64.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  uint8_t key[] = {50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50};
  //expressed in 16 unsigned in characters, be careful not to typecast this as a char in a decrypter
  //16- 50's (uint8) is the way to express 16 2's in ASCII, the encryption matches to what will show up on <a href="http://aesencryption.net/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://aesencryption.net/</a>
  char data[] = "0123456789012345";
  //The message to encrypt, 16 chars == 16 bytes, no padding needed as frame is 16 bytes
  char encryptedData[100];
  int *size;
  Serial.print("Message:");
  Serial.println(data);
  aes128_enc_single(key, data);
  Serial.print("encrypted:");
  Serial.println(data);
  int inputLen = sizeof(data);
  int encodedLen = base64_enc_len(inputLen);
  char encoded[encodedLen];
  base64_encode(encoded, data, inputLen);
  Serial.print("encrypted(base64):"); //used
  Serial.println(encoded);
  Serial.println("***********Decrypter************");
  int input2Len = sizeof(encoded);
  int decodedLen = base64_dec_len(encoded, input2Len);
  char decoded[decodedLen];
  base64_decode(decoded, encoded, input2Len);
  Serial.print("encrypted (returned from Base64):");
  Serial.println(decoded);
  Serial.print("decrypted:");
  Serial.println(decoded);
}

void loop() {
}
```

This is the Java code:

```
package main;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class ForTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String message= "0123456789012345";//Message to encode  
        String key = "2222222222222222";  
        // 128 bit key  -this key is processed as ASCII values  
        System.out.println("Processing 3.0 AES-128 ECB Encryption/Decryption Example");
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        System.out.println("Original Message: " + message);
        System.out.println("Key: " + key);
        System.out.println("key in bytes: "+key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("==========================");           
        //Encrypter
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec_encode = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        Cipher cipher_encode  = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        //          Cipher cipher_encode = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING"); //AES-CBC with IV encoding, ECB is used without the IV, example shown on <a href="http://aesencryption.net/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://aesencryption.net/</a> 
        cipher_encode.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec_encode);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher_encode.doFinal(message.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Encrypted String (base 64): "
                + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encrypted));
        //encode without padding: Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(encrypted));
        //encode with padding:  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted));
        String base64_encrypted = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encrypted);
        //Decrypter
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec_decode = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        Cipher cipher_decode  = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        //          Cipher cipher_decode = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher_decode.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec_decode);
        System.out.println("length: "+"Ouril+UTDF8htLzE".length());
        byte[] decrypted_original = cipher_decode.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("Ouril+UTDF8htLzEhiRj7wA="));
        String decrypt_originalString = new String(decrypted_original);
        System.out.println("Decrypted String: " + decrypt_originalString);
    }
}
```

In Java when I try to decrypt the encoded String by Arduino I get this:

```
Processing 3.0 AES-128 ECB Encryption/Decryption Example
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Original Message: 0123456789012345
Key: 2222222222222222
key in bytes: [B@2a139a55
==========================
Encrypted String (base 64): Ouril+UTDF8htLzEhiRj7w==
length: 16
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1016)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:960)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at main.ForTest.main(ForTest.java:46)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: The string you are trying to base64 decode and decrypt is `Ouril+UTDF8htLzEhiRj7wA=`, which is 17 bytes after base64 decoding, and has a trailing 0 byte. The string that gets printed earlier is `Ouril+UTDF8htLzEhiRj7w==`, which is identical (after base 64 decoding) except for that trailing byte, and is the correct length (16 bytes).

Comment: but why don't I get the same result after coding in base64 with arduino and Java? with Arduino I got : `Ouril+UTDF8htLzEhiRj7wA=` and with Java I got `Ouril+UTDF8htLzEhiRj7w==` and how can I correct that? thanks!

Comment: The Arduino output is introducing an extra byte. I'm not familiar with the Arduino language itself, but from a quick look, it's a subset of C/C++. C is famous for "null-terminating" its strings (i.e. to indicate the end of a string, which has arbitrary length, it adds a byte which contains the value `0x00`). This is likely what is happening here.

Comment: In your Java code, you need to trim the input cipher text to the byte prior to the `0x00` byte. In addition, your choice of `AES/ECB/NoPadding` will have severe issues if the input plaintext and cipher text are not exact multiples of 16 bytes (the block size for AES), and `ECB` is the worst cipher block mode (equivalent to _not encrypting_ for most purposes). Look at this Wikipedia entry on [cipher block modes of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) and select a better option (GCM suggested for AEAD properties).

Comment: You could also resolve this at the source and only Base64 encode the contents of the cipher text up to the null byte in Arduino, but I don't know enough of the language to say if there's an easy way to do that. You may just be able to trim the last byte from the `char[]` before encoding it.

Comment: @sabrina2020 Hi, Did you ever figure this out? I am running into the same issue and have been having a time trying to remove the null terminator at the end of Arduino Strings, char arrays, etc. Apparently, the compiler always plugs them in. Getting in sync with the way Arduino/C++ does AES base 64 encoding versus the way Java does AES base 64 encoding is driving me a little batty : ) I can get the AES base 64 encoding to work fine on Arduino to encrypt and decrypt but when I send it to my Java server it always throws a padding error. Thoughts?

Comment: The problem here is `sizeof(data)`. It should be `strlen(data)`. Otherwise you're including the trailing zero.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working after like a week - working Arduino documentation on integration with other systems is crap : )

Working Arduino code:

```
#include "mbedtls/aes.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <base64.h>

void makeUpdateAPICall()
{
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    HTTPClient http;

    // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
    http.begin(serverName); 

    // Specify content-type header
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    http.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer XXXXXXXX [whatever your web token is]");
    http.addHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    http.addHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");

    //AES Encrypt
    esp_aes_context aesOutgoing;
    unsigned char key[32] = "1234567812345678123456781234567" ;
    key[31] = '8';   // we replace the 32th (index 31) which contains '/0' with the '8' char.

    char *input = "Tech tutorials x";
    unsigned char encryptOutput[16];

    mbedtls_aes_init(&aesOutgoing);
    mbedtls_aes_setkey_enc(&aesOutgoing, key, 256);
    int encryptAttempt = mbedtls_aes_crypt_ecb(&aesOutgoing, MBEDTLS_AES_ENCRYPT, (const unsigned char *)input, encryptOutput);
    USE_SERIAL.println();
    USE_SERIAL.println("MBEDTLS_AES_EBC encryption result:\t ");
    USE_SERIAL.print(encryptAttempt); //0 means that the encrypt/decrypt function was successful
    USE_SERIAL.println();
    mbedtls_aes_free(&aesOutgoing);

    int encryptSize = sizeof(encryptOutput) / sizeof(const unsigned char);
    USE_SERIAL.println("Size of AES encrypted output: ");
    USE_SERIAL.println(encryptSize);

    //Base 64 Encrypt
    int inputStringLength = sizeof(encryptOutput);
    int encodedLength = Base64.decodedLength((char *)encryptOutput, inputStringLength);
    char encodedCharArray[encodedLength];
    Base64.encode(encodedCharArray, (char *)encryptOutput, inputStringLength);
    //Send to server
    USE_SERIAL.print("Sending to server.");
    int httpResponseCode = http.POST(encodedCharArray);

    String payload = "{}";

    if (httpResponseCode > 0)
    {
      //Retrieve server response
      payload = http.getString();
    }
    // Free resources
    http.end();
  }
  WiFi.disconnect();
}
```

Working Java code:

```
public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String key) {
```

```
    byte[] encryptionKeyBytes = key.getBytes();  
    Cipher cipher;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKeyBytes, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);         
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Working on the return process now.

You call the Java side with this code:

`final String decryptedText = AES.decrypt(encryptedStr, "12345678123456781234567812345678");
System.out.println("Decrypted AES ECB String: ");
System.out.println(decryptedText);`

Wanted to provide this for any poor slob who finds him/herself in the same boat : )

Hope this helps!

Comment: This isn't much use with the fixed size encryption output, and all the shenanigans with the key as a string isn't necessary: if you'd left it as in the OP that trailing null problem wouldn't have arisen.

Comment: @user207421 You are quite correct. However, the purpose of my example was just to provide a viable means of AES integration between Arduino & Java. There is really no documentation out there (at least that I could find). My production code for this uses padding, AES CBC, & pulls the key from a secure location on the server. Extracting the key from a secure location & the other stuff is more BAU, but the trick is getting the decrypt/encrypt pieces to work when they come from other systems/languages. Hopefully, this helps someone get over that hurdle.